# How to limit results to only future date in php

Tags: php, date

How to limit result to today date.

E.g. we have three dates in this format **(Y-m-d H:i:s)**:

```
$a = "2011-08-10 23:55:01";
$b = "2011-08-10 00:20:01";
$c = "2011-08-10 09:45:01";
```

and I don't want to echo dates that are past. I want just future dates to be shown.

How to make if then statement for future dates only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function and compare with the current time given by the [time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function:

```
if (strtotime($a) > time()) {
  echo $a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because I can't see if you're using this in a function somewhere, I chose to concatenate the dates into an array, and work with the array using a foreach:

```
$a = "2011-08-10 23:55:01";
$b = "2011-08-10 00:20:01";
$c = "2012-08-10 09:45:01";

$dates = array($a,$b,$c);

echo "<ul>";
foreach($dates as $k => $v) {
    if (strtotime($v) > time()){
        echo "<li>$v</li>";
        }
    }
echo "</ul>";
```

The above, at the time of writing, outputs:

- 2011-08-10 23:55:01
- 2012-08-10 09:45:01

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strtotime($a) > time()) {
    echo $a;
}
```